# How to fix Costura.AssemblyLoader causing stackoverflow with recursive loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, fody-costura

I currently have a program that is using Costura but there seems to be a stackoverflow error that causes it to crash. I checked the call stack and noticed that Costura.AssemblyLoader.ResolveAssembly and Costura.AssemblyLoader.ReadFromEmbeddedResources are getting called over and over again, resulting in a stackoverflow exception. I was wondering if anyone has experienced this before and if so, please let me know how you fixed this (or what this even means)

I have one project call another project via a method call. In this method, there is a dictionary in the parameter. I believe this is where the error is located as the stackoverflow exception happens right at this method call. This can be found in the stack with it repeating over and over again

`mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(byte\[\] rawAssembly) Unknown Program.exe!Costura.AssemblyLoader.ReadFromEmbeddedResources(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary\<string, string\> assemblyNames, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary\<string, string\> symbolNames, System.Reflection.AssemblyName requestedAssemblyName) Line 134 Unknown Program.exe!Costura.AssemblyLoader.ResolveAssembly(object sender, System.ResolveEventArgs e) Line 29    Unknown mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly assembly, string assemblyFullName)   Unknown \[Native to Managed Transition\]     \[Managed to Native Transition\]`